# order doesn't send in python metatrader5

Tags: request, trading, metatrader4, metatrader5

I am trying to send an order to the Metatrader 5 program, but nothing is happening today, and until yesterday it was giving error 10013

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5

mt5.initialize()


price = mt5.symbol_info_tick("NQ100_m_i").bid
print(price)
requester = {
        "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
        "symbol": "NQ100_m_i",
        "volume": float(0.15),
        "type": mt5.ORDER_TYPE_BUY,
        "price": price,
        "sl": 0,
        "tp": 0,
        "deviation": 30,
        "magic": 234000,
        "comment": 'sadsada',
        "type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_GTC,
        "type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_FOK,
    }
result = mt5.order_send(requester)


print(result)
```

.

I tried all the type_filling and type_time modes but still nothing happens and it says result is an nonetype object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of price = mt5.symbol_info_tick("NQ100_m_i").bid
try:
price = mt5.symbol_info_tick("NQ100_m_i").ask

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).